# Query not updating DB with WHERE clause in it

Tags: sql-server

Below query does not update;  if we have the WHERE clause in it.

```
UPDATE dbo.GBH_OCCU_FULL_Process 
SET ShortDescription= b.ShortDescription 
FROM dbo.GBH_OCCU  as b 
INNER JOIN dbo.GBH_OCCU_FULL_Process AS a ON a.[OccurrenceID] = b.[OccurrenceID]
WHERE a.[OccurrenceID] = '12-3456'
```

Comment: Easy way to start debugging is to comment out the `Update... SET...` line and replace it with `SELECT *`.  See if you're returning the data you expect.  I'm guessing you're not.

Comment: if i remove WHERE a.[OccurrenceID] = '12-3456' it will work fine. but i need to update one record not entire table

Comment: does GBH_OCCU_FULL_Process  table having the occurenceid 12-3456. can you check it

Comment: @Ahmad
can you try this
Update 
   a
SET 
   ShortDescription= b.ShortDescription 
FROM 
   dbo.GBH_OCCU  as b 
   inner join  
   dbo.GBH_OCCU_FULL_Process as a 
       ON a.[OccurrenceID] = b.[OccurrenceID]
WHERE a.[OccurrenceID] = '12-3456'